# How to associate variable values from a df to another

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with three values, x and y are coordinates and z is the value of the indipendent variable:

```
x.range <- c(1,10)
y.range <- c(20,50)
grid <- expand.grid(x = seq(x.range[1], x.range[2], by=0.5), 
                       y = seq(y.range[1], y.range[2], by=0.5))
grid$z <- runif(nrow(grid),10, 70)
```

Now i have another dataframe like this with only x and y values:

```
x1 <- c(3.7,5.4,9.2)
y1 <- c(41.1,30.3,22.9)
df <- data.frame(x=x1,y=y1)
```

Now i want to associate to the points of dataframe `df` the z value of the nearest point of dataframe `grid` (with the shortest distance). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the prettiest, but works

```
apply(df, 1, 
      function(x){
        pythag <- sqrt((x[1] - grid$x)^2 + 
                       (x[2] - grid$y)^2)
        grid[which.min(pythag), "z"]
      })
```

Simply returning the value for the nearest point using Pythagoras.

## Edit

Recoding to adhere to coding standards:

```
pythag <- function(x, y, g){
  which.min(((x - g$x)^2 + (y - g$y)^2)^0.5)
}

idx <- mapply(FUN = pythag,
              x = df[["x"]], 
              y = df[["y"]], 
              MoreArgs = list(g = grid))

grid[idx,]
```

Comment: I agree with using Pythagorean theorem to calculate distance but this didn't work for me. It outputted 3 values that are not in `grid$z`

Comment: I have recoded it, to the same effect. It could be because you are using a random number generator. Use `set.seed(42)` (it doesn't have to be 42) before running to get reproducable value.

Comment: I think an issue here may be that your distance metric does not include the `z` component.

Comment: @aichao, the z value is an independent value, a value that should be returned, according to the question setter.